# Suggest MVC frameworks that do not use controller base classes

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, language-agnostic, web-applications

Pseudo-code:

```
class SomeController {
  def myAction() {
    // controler is an property passed via ctor
    controller.redirect(toWhereever)
  }
}

// another variant
class AnotherController {
  def myAction(controller) {
    // controler is an method argument
    controller.redirect(toWhereever)
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Because the question is a bit dry you could try to spice up your answers with some experience with the framework and what do you think is *better* with that approach.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: I'm looking for frameworks that favor composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [web2py](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Default-Application,-Controller-and-Function) - controllers are functions
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/)
- [puremvc](http://puremvc.org/) - controllers are *Commands*
- [camping](http://stuff.judofyr.net/camping-docs/book/02_getting_started.html) - odd, replaces internal controllers
- [limonade](http://www.limonade-php.net/) - procedural

Answer (score 7):

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) (built ontop of spring) favour dependency injection with no inheritance whatsoever. Each controller is a class that does not extend anything. Instead you can inject other components into it (using dependency-injection). For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

     @Inject
     private UserService service;

     @RequestMapping("/register")
     public String register(User user) {..}

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
     @Inject
     private UserController userController
}
```

(Although it is not a common practice to inject controllers into other controllers, you can inject any object)

Answer (score 2):

Django has decided to use different terms for the MVC pattern.  In django-speak "view" is what most people call controller.  a django view is just a function taking a request instance and returning a response instance.  Roughly it looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    if request.method != 'GET':
        raise Http404
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Is it the recommended/only way to use django or do they have more "classical" ways?

Comment: This is taken right from the examples given when introducing request handling in the django docs.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/views/  As far as i know, django does not provide an "Object oriented request handler" concept, though it does provide some useful objects for request handling functions, and some great generic handlers.

Answer (score 0):

JSF & Spring MVC

An easy tutorial for JSF: **www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/index.html#Annotations**

A basic example from SpringSource: **http://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk**

### Q: Why JSF

A:
You can perform your action at SimpleController#doSomething

```
@ManagedBean 
public class SimpleController {  

  public String doSomething() {
    ...
  }

}
```

And SimpleController does not extend any controller, @ManagedBean helps to make it look like a controller.

### Q: Why Spring MVC

A:
You can perform your action at "..../doSomething"

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {  

      @RequestMapping("/doSomething")
  public String doSomething() {
    ...
  }

}
```

SimpleController does not extend any controller.

- @Controller helps to make the class a controller
- @RequestMapping bind its url to "/doSomething"

[sorry for bold url, i can only post maximum one url in an answer as a newbie :-S]

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 also lets you do this. All the actions are simple java beans.